# iOS Custom Unicode font across apps

Tags: ios, unicode, fonts

I'm looking to replicate the functionality in this app - [appstore.com/coolfonts](http://appstore.com/coolfonts)

I'd like to enter the text using a custom unicode font and then when I copy it over to say - Safari it should stay with the same font (you can see the behavior in the app).

So obviously I should use unicode characters, but is there like a font with given characters or do I have to convert them somehow?

I'd appreciate some help on this.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

After some days of research - as best I can tell - the developer has a map of english characters to unicode characters and uses the text view delegate methods to replace them upon typing.
Hence why it doesn't work with other languages other than English.

If someone figures out a better way - let me know.